# Trouble passing angular resolve values into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I pass the resolve validToken value to my controller?

Config:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/recover/:token', {
    templateUrl: 'recover.html',
    controller: 'recoverCtrl',
    resolve: {
        validToken : function(){
            return "INVALID TOKEN"
        }
    }
  });
}])
```

Controller:

```
.controller('recoverCtrl', ['$location','$scope','$http', '$routeParams', '$rootScope',
    function($location,$scope,$http,$routeParams,$rootScope,validToken) {
       console.log(validToken);
       // Rest of controller code.
    }
]);
```

I would like to do this without removing the `[]`'s so the code could eventually be minifed. The below example is working as I expected so I know that all of my code it working, I'm just not sure what I should add to the above code to make it function similarly.

```
.controller('recoverCtrl', function($location,$scope,$http,$routeParams,$rootScope,validToken) {
    console.log(validToken);
    //Other code
});
```

Comment: How do you expect it to work? `validToken` won't be injected because it's not in dependency array. Pass it as any other dependency.

Comment: thanks @estus, i swear I tried that at one point and it didn't work.

Comment: You're welcome. DI is really straightforward under the hood, so it remains a mystery why it would not work. This won't work if a controller is not route controller but nested controller in view, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to Etsus.

I just needed to add the object key as a string while injecting and it was able to determine that it was a resolve key

```
.controller('recoverCtrl', ['$location','$scope','$http', '$routeParams', '$rootScope', 'validToken', function ($location, $scope, $http, $routeParams,  rootScope, validToken) {
    console.log(validToken);
}]);
```